# java lang NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, pageobjects, findby

Using an example from Selenium Wedriver Practical Guide (to login in and create a test post on Wordpress), I encounter the above mentioned error.

Here is the PageObject that I am using:

```
package com.PageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

/**
 * Created by JTester on 3/9/2016.
 */
public class AdminLoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID, id="user_login")
    WebElement email;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID, id="user_pass")
    WebElement pwd;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID, id="wp-submit")
    WebElement submit;

    public AdminLoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        driver.get("http://mysite.wordpress.com/wp-admin/");
        }

    public void login(){
        email.sendKeys("myEmailAddress@yahoo.com");
        pwd.sendKeys("myPasswd");
        submit.click();
    }

}
```

And here is the test class:

```
package com.features.trial;

import com.PageObjects.AdminLoginPage;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

/**
 * Created by JTester on 3/9/2016.
 */
public class TestAddNewPost {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //login to wordpress admin
        AdminLoginPage admLoginPage = new AdminLoginPage(driver);
        admLoginPage.login();

        //go to AllPosts page
        driver.get("http://mysite.wordpress.com/wp-admin/edit.php");

        //add a new post
        WebElement addNewPost = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add New"));
        addNewPost.click();

        //add new post's content
        driver.switchTo().frame("content_ifr");
        WebElement postBody = driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce"));
        postBody.sendKeys("This is my description.");
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.id("title"));
        title.sendKeys("This is my first post");

        //publish my post
        WebElement publish = driver.findElement(By.id("publish"));
        publish.click();
        }
}
```

Since I am new to Selenium and Page Objects, could anyone explain why it is throwing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.PageObjects.AdminLoginPage.login(AdminLoginPage.java:29)
    at com.features.trial.TestAddNewPost.main(TestAddNewPost.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Many thanks..

ps: After looking at a lot of code examples on the web, I think I need to use PageFactory to instantiate my elements but not sure if this is true, and if it is, how do I go about it using my example code.

Debugger Screenshot :
[image]

Comment: What happens when you use a debugger and inspect the field state of `AdminLoginPage` in the `login` method?

Comment: @Dai, Okay, quite new to this, so can you dumb it down for me? How do I inspect the field state? Using intelliJ.. In the Debugger, I notice it says Variables, and under that it shows the following: !Frame is not available..

Comment: @Dai, Okay, having clicked on the TestAddNewPost class with the Debugger, I get a list of Variables? But what it means, I am not sure. Too new to this, to make sense of it :-( See end of post for screen capture.

Comment: Solved.. I was correct in saying that I needed PageFactory to instantiate my elements.. I have changed the TestAddNewPost class to reflect this..

Comment: For future reference, your stack trace includes line numbers. Your pasted code does not. So folks reading your question still have no idea what line the exception came from. I'll leave figuring out how to help readers see where your errors are as an exercise to you.

Comment: @Jason C, noted for next time I post.

Answer (score 0):

AdminLoginPage should have been initialized using PageFactory.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public AdminLoginPage(WebDriver driver){
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);  //add this
    this.driver = driver;
    driver.get("http://mysite.wordpress.com/wp-admin/");
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works for me too. I have posted an answer too, but which is better. I think yours? Better to instantiate PageFactory from within the PageObject, than TestAddNewPost class..

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```
AdminLoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver,AdminLoginPage.class);
        loginPage.login();
```

to the TestAddNewPost class, instead of using the existing code:

```
AdminLoginPage admLoginPage = new AdminLoginPage(driver);
        admLoginPage.login();
```